# Issue using abstract base entity class with collection property of abstract child types

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

Adding a new feature to an application with database entities that resemble this schema:

```
public abstract class Team
{
    [Key]
    public Guid TeamId { get; set; }

    [MaxLength(100)]
    public string? Name { get; set; }

    public abstract IEnumerable<Player> Players { get; }
}

public abstract class Team<TPlayer> : Team where TPlayer : Player
{
    public override ICollection<TPlayer> Players { get; } = new HashSet<TPlayer>();
}

public class BaseballTeam : Team<BaseballPlayer>
{
    public int WorldSeriesAppearances { get; set; }
}

public class FootballTeam : Team<FootballPlayer>
{
    public int SuperBowlAppearances { get; set; }
}

public abstract class Player
{
    [Key]
    public Guid PlayerId { get; set; }
    public Guid TeamId { get; set; }

    [MaxLength(100)]
    public string? Name { get; set; }
    public virtual Team Team { get; set; } = null!;
}

public class BaseballPlayer : Player
{

}

public class FootballPlayer : Player
{

}
```

Every `Team` has a set  of `Player`, but the players are of a derived type depending on the team. I need to be able to iterate over teams and their players regardless of the derived type. `Team<TPlayer>` intermediate abstract class exists just to prevent having to duplicate the `Players` override in each derived class.

This is all valid C#, I am able to construct and use these classes in memory, they worked in my unit tests, and I was able to generate and apply a database Migration using them. However issues have come up using them in an actual EF Core `DbContext`. (Data to the tables was inserted using raw SQL, not EF Core). When I attempt to insert or query the tables from EF Core I get this error:

```
The type of navigation 'Team.Players' is 'HashSet<BaseballPlayer>' which does not implement 'ICollection<Player>'. Collection navigations must implement 'ICollection<>' of the target type
```

Looking for some change, configuration, or workaround to get these classes working.

Comment: Hmm, in what C# version `public abstract IEnumerable<Player> Players { get; }` and `public override ICollection<TPlayer> Players { get; }` is a valid C# code?

Comment: @IvanStoev C# 9 added covariant returns but it requires framework support, although that's provided here.

Comment: Seems overly complicated. Why have two tiers of abstract team classes? Actually, in spite of what I said to Ivan I don't think that code is valid after all because the overriding property definitions are not covariantly valid

Comment: @AluanHaddad the intermediate `Team<TPlayer>` is there just so avoid having to override `Players` in each base class. Actual production code has many more derived types.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that EF Core requires that Collection Properties be of type `ICollection<T>`, not `IEnumerable<T>`.

I accomplished what I needed to by using a different collection property in the base class. `Team` now has this instead:

```
public abstract class Team
{
    [Key]
    public Guid TeamId { get; set; }

    [MaxLength(100)]
    public string? Name { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Provides a list of all <see cref="Player"/>s for the
    /// Team. Should be treated as read-only. Do not ever add items
    /// to this property. Use <see cref="Team{TPlayer}
    /// .Players" /> in a derived type when modifying the collection.
    /// </summary>
    public abstract ICollection<Player> PlayerList { get; }
}

public abstract class Team<TPlayer> : Team where TPlayer : Player
{
    public override ICollection<Player> PlayerList =>
        Players.Select(p => p as Player).ToList();

    public virtual ICollection<TPlayer> Players { get; } = new HashSet<TPlayer>();
}
```

Not the most elegant solution but it results in the schema I want and I am able to query `Team` data and include `Players` on all Team types, etc.

Answer (score -1):

The issue you're facing is due to the fact that EF Core expects the navigation property to be of type ICollection, where T is the target type, in this case, Player. However, in your code, the Players property is of type ICollection, where TPlayer is a derived type of Player.
Can you revise your code like this

```
public abstract class Team<TPlayer> : Team where TPlayer : Player
{
    public override ICollection<Player> Players { get; } = new HashSet<TPlayer>();
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately that won't compile.